# How to filter task based on user input fields in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make a Search form where user can search others tasks based on country, city, location, gender, age, date of birth, etc. Here is my search form...

```
  <%= form_for(@othertask, url: "/other_task", :html =>{:method => :post}) do |f| %>
 <%= select_tag "country", options_for_select([], params[:country]), {:multiple => false, :class => "countries", :'data-country' => "IN", :id => "countries_states1"} %>
 <%= select_tag :state, options_for_select([], params[:state]), { :class => "states", :'data-country' => "countries_states1", :'data-state' => ""} %>
 <%= text_field_tag :city, params[:city], :placeholder => "City"%>                
 <%= text_field_tag :dob, params[:dob], :placeholder => "date of birth", :id => "dp2" %>
 <%= select_tag :highlyeducation, options_for_select(["ME/MTech","MCom","MCA","BE/BTech","MBA","BCA/BSc","BCom"], params[:higheducation]), {:multiple => false} %>
 <%= radio_button_tag :gender,'Male', params[:male] %>Male
 <%= radio_button_tag :gender,'Female', params[:female] %>Female <br/><br/>
 <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-large" %>
```

Here is my controller --

```
  def create

    if @other_tasks = Micropost.joins(:user).where('users.city' => params[:city], 'users.country' => params[:country])  
    render 'index'
    else
      @other_tasks = []
    render 'index'
    end
 end
```

A user can search by filling zero, one, two or all fields. For this If i make all possible combination to fetch all tasks it takes lots of queries to write. How can i fetch tasks based on user input by using only one query.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how tasks are connected to Microposts in your domain and why do you use the create action in order to search for tasks. I think clarification of these matters will help you get a better answer.

What you need to do is to group all the searchable fields into an array and apply the filter whenever the value received for that field in params is not blank:

```
def create
  @other_tasks =  Micropost.joins(:user)
  search_fields = [:country, :state, :city, :dob, :highlyeducation]
  search_fields.each do |f|
    @other_tasks = @other_tasks.where("users.#{f} = ?", params[f]) unless params[f].blank?
  end
  render :index
end
```